# Todo list refreshing there is a list item with empty name and buttons

Tags: react-hooks

When I'm refreshing or first opening there is a list item with empty name and its buttons. Moreover i can't disappear the empty line when i'm using && this in todolist still shows.when im console.log(todos) i got array with 1 item on it.
How can i solve this problem?

```
const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([{
    userInput: null,
    isDone: false,
  }])
  
  const addItem = (userInput) => {
    const newTodos = [...todos, {userInput}]
    setTodos(newTodos)
  }
  const markItem = index =>{
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos[index].isDone = true;
    setTodos(newTodos);
  }

  const removeItem = index => {
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos.splice(index,1);
    setTodos(newTodos)
  }


  return (
    <div className=>
      <Calender />
      <TodoInput addItem={addItem} />
      {(todos?.length > 0 )  && <TodoList todos={todos} removeItem={removeItem} markItem={markItem} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;




const TodoList = ({ todos,removeItem,markItem }) => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {todos?.map((todo,index) => {
          return (
           <li key={index} >
             <TodoItem todo={todo} index={index} removeItem={removeItem} markItem={markItem} />
          </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>

    </div>
  )
}




   


const TodoItem = ({todo,index,removeItem,markItem}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <span className={(todo.isDone ? "line-through" : "")}>{todo.userInput}</span>
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>markItem(index)}>✔</button> 
            <button onClick={()=>removeItem(index)}>X</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoItem
```

Why there is empty task like in the image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned 1 item in useState

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([{
  userInput: null,
  isDone: false,
}])
```

You should declare it empty

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
```